# how to set v-text-field height in vuetify3?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

v-text-field dont have height props in vuetify3.
only have density prop ('default' | 'comfortable' | 'compact').

v-autocomplate, v-checkbox also.

i try modify css, but There are so many classes in v-text-field that I don't know what to modify.

Comment: if you want to change the height, it's better to use v-textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I changed the `height` Property to `min-height`.

```cs
.v-field__input {
   height : 22px
}
```

change to

```css
.v-field__input {
   min-height : 22px
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but seems not lucky, could you please guide me how to make this with custom height?  <template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field v-model="msg" />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>